# Lego Mindstorm NXT 2.0: "Error: NXT Bluetooth passkey confirmation failed"

Tags: lego-mindstorms, nxt

Running Windows 7 and the Lego Mindstorms NXT 2.0 IDE. The Windows bluetooth manager shows the NXT is connected and the NXT shows up in the Windows list of bluetooth devices. When I try to connect from the Lego IDE, however, I get a message that says "Error: NXT Bluetooth passkey confirmation failed".

I entered the pairing key on the NXT and within Windows with no problems. The problem is when I am in the IDE trying to connect to the NXT.

Any suggestions?

Update - January 8, 2010

I have it working on one computer. It's a desktop PC running Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit. Same BT adapter, I just didn't install the vendor supplied drivers. I used the default Win 7 BT drivers. I'm gonna try it on my Win7 notebook in a clean boot-to-VHD.

Update - January 12, 2010

Booted into a VHD, plugged in the BT adapter, did not install the manufacturer's drivers, and the mindstorm - BT connection works.

I tried removing all the manufacturer's driver from my main Win7 installation but still have this problem.

Comment: You may be interested to hear that there is a proposal for a StackOverflow style [site for Lego Mindstorms](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4105/lego-mindstorms-robotics?referrer=xdbfIk67GZl3hJ0vc5L2Fg2) on [Area51.stackexchange.com](http://Area51.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Folks - at the risk of repeating something obvious, try running the program as the administrator.

Comment: that's the only way I roll... usually.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

Found this thread on the Lego forums: http://messageboards.lego.com/en-US/showpost.aspx?PostID=1000676827&PageIndex=3 which suggests that it is some kind of Windows permissions issue for a program that really is written for Windows XP

Note that I did NOT manage to solve it on my machine by running the Mindstorms program in Windows XP SP2-compatible mode.  I get the -142005 error still after that.  On Windows Vista 32-bit, Vista Business.  On an IBM Thinkpad.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [BricxCC IDE](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/) on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit on my HP laptop.

First, I installed the correct drivers from the disk that came with the kit.

Then, I used the builtin windows bluetooth manager to connect to my Mindstorm NXT 2.0. I was asked to provide a passcode that I manually configured on the NXT and then typed into the bluetooth connection on my laptop.

The final step was to choose the correct port (BTH::NXT) and brick type in the bricxcc interface.

From then on, everything worked fine.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Although the official [website](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/bluetooth/default.aspx) admits that they continue to have issues, I managed to establish a workaround via a serial connection over the existing Broadcom/Microsoft Bluetooth driver on my HP ENVY laptop - Windows 7 configuration. Here's what I did:

1. Upgrade to the latest firmware (1.31?)
2. Download Fhantom driver

When NXT connected to the laptop, I saw the driver getting installed, indicating a serial connection over Bluetooth (COM3), please refer to the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us9g3.png).

I hope it helps!