# Python Bluetooth Passkey/Password Linux

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I'm working on a Python script to control my Mindstorms NXT with a Raspberry Pi.
My problem is, that the NXT has a Bluetooth passkey. You can change the passkey but not delete it.

I want to know how you can connect the PyBluez socket to a device with a passkey.

This is the  current program:

```
import bluetooth
import socket

target_name = "Jerry"
target_address = None

print "performing inquiry..."
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
print "found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices)

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
        target_address = bdaddr
        break

if target_address is not None:
    print "found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address
else:
    print "could not find target bluetooth device nearby"

bluesock= socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
bluesock.connect((target_address, 1))
```

Comment: Markus Blechschmidt, what is exact problem and what is your question?

Comment: I added a bounty because I have a related problem. The closest that bluetooth (as described above) comes to connecting to the devices is that a ping is sent the NXT asks for a password. (Supposedly this has to do with the computer initiating contact - not the NXT). Looking at the NXT documentation didn't hint at any passkeys. This looks related but it's not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972605/lego-mindstorm-nxt-2-0-error-nxt-bluetooth-passkey-confirmation-failed

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's a Python specific answer. The py-nxt posts I saw seemed to point at the OS.

Does starting this background process (on your computer) with a passkey help you?

```
bluetooth-agent 1234 &
```

I've found it useful to pair with the NXT first using:

```
hcitool cc 00:16:53:0A:17:16
```

Whereby, I'd found the MAC address with:

```
hcitool scan
```

If you hadn't already tried the rfcomm related bits for Linux, there's a worthwhile ref [here](http://www.heatxsink.com/entry/how-to-pair-a-bluetooth-device-from-command-line-on-linux).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I just had to go into go into Bluetooth settings and pair with the device, entering the passkey on Windows and then on the NXT. It never showed a screen saying that it had paired, seemingly getting stuck pairing, but it did work and I was able to connect with nxt-python.